# Prove $\cos x = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_n \frac{n\sin 2nx}{4n^2-1}$ with Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I want to prove $$\cos x = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_n \frac{n\sin 2nx}{4n^2-1}\;x\in(0,2\pi)\;\;\;\;[1]$$

I have two questions regarding this:

$(1)$ How can I find a function $f$ such that the former series can be obtained using the Fourier series of $f$? I know the Fourier series will be given by

$$f(x)=a_0+\sum_n\left(a_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}+b_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

then should I asssume that the $\cos$ in the left hand side of $[1]$ is the $\cos$ inside the latter series?

Since no $\pi$ appear in the denominator of $[1]$, and $n\sin 2nx=n\sin nx\cos nx$ I thought that could $a_n=n\sin nx$ or $b_n =n\cos nx$ but these terms are given by definite integrals so no $x$ term can appear in them.

An alternative approach could be using $L=\pi/2$, then it must be $b_n=\frac{n}{4n^2-1}$, but this would imply $\frac{n}{4n^2-1}=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\sin nx dx$, and I'm having some issues to get ride of the sine.

$(2)$ In the general case, given any series how can I proceed to find the function $f$?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is an answer for (2). For (1) take $f(x)=\cos(x)$ for all $x\in ]0,2\pi[$ and $L=\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the interval to be $0<x<\color{blue}{\pi}$, because then you can show
$$
\cos x = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\sin(2nx)}{4n^2-1}, \quad x\in(0,\color{blue}{\pi}).\tag{1}
$$
as follows.

In this case, the standard computation of Fourier sine coefficients for the series
$$
\cos x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx),\quad 0<x<\pi,
$$
yields
\begin{align}
b_n={2\over \pi}\int_0^\pi  \cos x\sin(nx)\,dx
&=
\begin{cases}
0, & n=1,\\
{2n(1+(-1)^n)\over \pi(n^2-1)}, &n=2,3,\dots,
\end{cases}
\\
&=
\begin{cases}
0, & n=1,3,5,\dots\\
{4n\over \pi(n^2-1)}, &n=2,4,6,\dots
\end{cases}
\end{align}
That is,
$$
\cos x=\sum_{n\text{ even}}{4n\over \pi(n^2-1)}\sin(nx)
%=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {4(2k)\over \pi((2k)^2-1)}\sin(2kx)\ \ 
\overset{\color{blue}{n=2k}}{=}\ \ \sum_{k=1}^\infty {8k\over \pi(4k^2-1)}\sin(2kx),
$$
which is $(1)$.